# Datatables with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I'm new to dataTabels and I'm trying to get data from a json txt file (test1.txt). This is a part of it (only 4) but I have +5000:

```
[{"0":"22352442","ID":"22352442","1":"22126303","PARENT":"22126303","2":"2813340","TASK_ID":"2813340","3":"2667252","CHILD_ID":"2667252","9":"Shawne Walthall","LEAD":"Shawne Walthall","11":"RP ~217' cable- PL 8 YPSIL","DESCRIPTION":"RP ~217' cable- PL 8 YPSIL","12":"PD-SW-ANN","WORKLOCATION":"PD-SW-ANN","13":"IC","TASKTYPE":"IC","14":"HOLD","STATUS":"HOLD","15":"INFLD","C_STATUS":"INFLD","16":"Scheduled","CLASSIFICATION":"Scheduled","18":"RFW672917A11 INSTALL CABLE - 05-181","TASK_DESCRIPTION":"RFW672917A11 INSTALL CABLE - 05-181","19":"Overload","TYPE_OF_WORK":"Overload","20":"16-NOV-06","TS":"16-NOV-06","21":"24-JAN-11","TC":"24-JAN-11"},{"0":"27364695","ID":"27364695","1":"27364637","PARENT":"27364637","2":"11949147","TASK_ID":"11949147","3":"11949089","CHILD_ID":"11949089","11":"08-036 Design System Cable NF 52R Howard","DESCRIPTION":"08-036 Design System Cable NF 52R Howard","12":"PD-SE-TBY","WORKLOCATION":"PD-SE-TBY","13":"TC","TASKTYPE":"TC","14":"WAPPR","STATUS":"WAPPR","15":"INFLD","C_STATUS":"INFLD","16":"Scheduled","CLASSIFICATION":"Scheduled","18":"TEST CABLE","TASK_DESCRIPTION":"TEST CABLE"},{"0":"28728012","ID":"28728012","1":"28728001","PARENT":"28728001","2":"31575951","TASK_ID":"31575951","3":"31575940","CHILD_ID":"31575940","9":"Clifton Manus","LEAD":"Clifton Manus","11":"08-098, Design\/Construct System Cable","DESCRIPTION":"08-098, Design\/Construct System Cable","12":"PD-SE-TBY","WORKLOCATION":"PD-SE-TBY","13":"IC","TASKTYPE":"IC","14":"APPR","STATUS":"APPR","15":"INFLD","C_STATUS":"INFLD","16":"Scheduled","CLASSIFICATION":"Scheduled","18":"08-097, INSTALL CABLE","TASK_DESCRIPTION":"08-097, INSTALL CABLE","19":"Reliability","TYPE_OF_WORK":"Reliability","20":"12-AUG-08","TS":"12-AUG-08","21":"12-AUG-17","TC":"12-AUG-17"},{"0":"28728014","ID":"28728014","1":"28728001","PARENT":"28728001","2":"31575953","TASK_ID":"31575953","3":"31575940","CHILD_ID":"31575940","11":"08-098, Design\/Construct System Cable","DESCRIPTION":"08-098, Design\/Construct System Cable","12":"PD-SE-TBY","WORKLOCATION":"PD-SE-TBY","13":"TC","TASKTYPE":"TC","14":"WAPPR","STATUS":"WAPPR","15":"INFLD","C_STATUS":"INFLD","16":"Scheduled","CLASSIFICATION":"Scheduled","18":"TEST CABLE","TASK_DESCRIPTION":"TEST CABLE","19":"Reliability","TYPE_OF_WORK":"Reliability","20":"12-AUG-08","TS":"12-AUG-08","21":"12-AUG-08","TC":"12-AUG-08"}]
```

There is around 21 columns. How can I assign this to the columns in my dataTable? 
This is my dataTable script:

```
var dataTables = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    ajax: "test1.txt",
    deferRender: true,
    bPaginate: true,
    select: {
        style: 'multi'
    },
    aLengthMenu: [[100, 200, 500, -1], [100, 200, 500, "All"]],
    pageLength: 100});
```

Comment: Here is a good example of how your data source should be formatted. https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location

Comment: And why your json file having duplicate values with different keys?
"0":"22352442","ID":"22352442"

Comment: ajax: "test1.txt",
       columns: [
       {data: "PARENT"},
       {data: "ID"},
       {data: "SR"},
       {data: "LEAD"},
       {data: "STATION"},
       {data: "WORKLOCATION"},
       {data: "TASKTYPE"},
       {data: "TASK_DESCRIPTION"},
       {data: "STATUS"},
       {data: "C_STATUS"},
       {data: "DESCRIPTION"},
       {data: "CLASSIFICATION"},
       {data: "RSD_STATUS"},
       {data: "RESOURCE_LOCATION"},
       {data: "TYPE_OF_WORK"},
       {data: "TS"},
       {data: "TC"},
       {data: "ACTSTART"}
       ]

Comment: I tried the above but still didnt render in my table. Any mistakes here?

Comment: Oh! See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in your datatable initialization.

```
ajax: {
    url: "test1.txt",
    dataSrc: ''
},
```

Remove `columns: [ ]`

You will then need to format your json text file such as this

```
[
    {
        "0" : "value of 1st column of 1st record",
        "1" : "value of 2nd column of 1st record",
        ...
        ...
        upto 21 column
    },
    {
        "0" : "value of 1st column of 2nd record",
        "1" : "value of 2nd column of 2nd record",
        ...
        ...
        upto 21 column
    }
]
```

Try this and see if it works.

If you want to hide column, then add this in datatable

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0, 1 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ]
```

Where `0, 1` represents you column index.
0 first column, 1 second column
Enter these index number of column which you want to hide.

**New Update**
In the dynamic json file case, you will need to use first approach using columns
Mention what columns you want to show in the columns key like below

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        url: "test1.txt",
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "C1" },
        { "data": "C2" }
    ]
});
```

and then your json text file will be like

```
[{"C1":"22352442","C2":"22126303","KEY":"NO SHOW"}, {"C1":"22352442","C2":"22126303", "KEY":"NO SHOW"}]
```

> Your first json will work in the case now.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me but I don't wantto show all the keys of the json file in my table. For example if I want to use like 5 of keys of these 21 only and not all of the 21 what would be a solution here!? so I mean here to specify which keys I need to show

Comment: @JawadSleiman You mean you want hide some of the columns from table on front end. Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean

Comment: That was close but the thing is that its hiding the columns in dataTables. What I mean exactly is that I have 18 columns in my dataTable and my json(most updated) have 23 keys, so I want 18 out of 23 to show in my datatable and my datatable columns not sorted as it is in my json. Is there a way to pull this 18 keys from json and sort them as I want in my datatable?

Comment: Is this test1.txt file generates dynamically?

Comment: yes it generates dynamically but with 23 keys as now. It will stay 23.

Comment: See 'New Update' answer.